# Count the all line in PHP self and add something after the last line

Tags: php

I want to count all the line by self then add string after the last line, how is it possible?

```
$file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);   
$no_of_lines = count(file($file));
```

this code will count the lines, but I want to add string in the last line.. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use file_put_contents

```
<?php

  $string= "text for last line";
  file_put_contents("randomFile.txt", $string, FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

Comment: good idea,
but I don't want randomfile,txt

I want it in the same file,,, how can I do it?

Comment: @Juliajane You have to define the filename there, it doesn't have to be randomFile.txt.

Comment: @Juliajane Just replace randomFile.txt with your own file.